# Getting an error parsing WSDL in Eclipse but not in SOAP UI, or NetBeans

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I have an eclipse project and I'm trying to add a reference to the webservice http://cm.eurotax.at/EtxVehDataServices.svc?wsdl

However when I complete the Web Service Client wizard in Eclipse I get the error:

`WAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:  java.io.IOException: ERROR: Missing <soap:fault> element inFault "wsFaultFault" in operation "wsFaultFault", in binding ws_GetAllVehTypes`

However when I take the identical web service and use the NetBeans web service generator it works perfectly. Equally SoapUI is able to parse it just fine.

I tried installing the Apache Axis2 plugin on eclipse but the new menu option that is supposed to appear never appeared.

So is there any way to get Eclipse to generate the code for this WSDL?

Comment: Did you try validate wsdl with wsimport or wsdlvalidator from apache?

Comment: @mlethys I'm having firewall problems running wsdlanalyzer against it. I did save the WSDL and upload it to WSDL Analyzer though, it validated structure ok with 1 warning about the consistency of top level element names.

Comment: I think I found the problem, the WSDL parser is using an old version of the SOAP protocol and looking for soap:fault instead of soap12:fault